# Searching google images from java code

Tags: java

I am writing a java code.
I want to search a string on google and google images using my java code.

Previously i wasnt even able to search text and then i had to register with google and then i could do it.

Now i want to search a string against googleimages

How can i do it?

Regards
Manjot

Comment: Errr, yes .. i think you can. Post what you have done so far, which API you are using, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with ChssPly76, but you have to include version number in URL as following

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?**v=1.0**&q=

put q= watever you want to search for.

I hope it will help you.
Cheers.

Comment: the API is no longer available

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty similar to text search, you just need to specify the URL as

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images
```

Standard arguments are described [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_intro_fonje), image -specific ones are [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_fonje_image).

Comment: Thanx for the URL, its works fine but it is returning only 4 items in a "results" array, do you how do i get more?

Comment: Same question as Paresh