# Searching Google Images from Java

Tags: java, google-image-search

I would have had the answer to my question here: [Searching google images from java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529737/searching-google-images-from-java-code) , but the library is deprecated, and I don't want to screw over this research project that I am working on by using that deprecated source.

**Tell me, what are you working on?**

I am trying to, for my research project, create an application that searches for depictions of medical terms (like, for example, alopecia), as well as two associated terms with it (such as hair loss). The end user is to choose pictures associated with the terms, which is associated with the original medical term.

[image: Here is how it was shown (and described to me)]

Those random pictures above T1,T2 are the images retrieved from Google Images for T1, T2 , and the T's are the terms being searched for.

Comment: I have obtained a search engine from Google Custom Search, and was thinking about web-scraping the results. Is this really the best way to go about it? (I hope not, because when I load it in my browser, the image results don't have HTML that can be scraped!!)

Comment: I might even try GoogleAppEngine, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/results , but I don't know how to get the images!!

Comment: Have you checked this out?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485578/how-do-save-image-from-google-images-using-google-api

Comment: Yes, I did. It led me to create a custom search engine, as the answer to that question involved using a deprecated service. However,I cannot seem to scrape that search engine's search results. Also, as per the stated requirements of this project, this should all be done programmatically, and loaded for the user. This means that the user should not even be seeing that search engine.

Dammit, Google, why did you have to go deprecating a good service!?!?!

Comment: I have settled on doing this: http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/search_google_programmatically.php . Of course, I would need to obtain an API key first, as per these instructions: http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/get_google_api_key.php . What I need to know now is what type of key I would need. How do I determine this?? How do I use the key??

If someone cannot answer my question, my team's research project is done for, as my application would be no use to them. SOMEONE, PLEASE HELP!!